# How do you split codes in Javascript? (import/export)

Tags: javascript, module

I've been trying to use ES6 codes to split up my codes so I won't have everything all on my main.js

I've tried to use import/export such as:

```
 //example1.js
 export var str = 'hello world';

 //main.js
 import exampleStr from './example1';
```

However, I will get the following error:

**Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier**

From what I had google'd, current web browsers do not support modules and I am using Google Chrome.

I tried to use **Babel** and **Webpack** but both of these seem to require everything to be bundled together. Even then, everything was even more confusing.

How would people split up their codes using **import/export** or do people simply use **script tags** to import their js files?

I am currently using Atom as well to program javascript/html.

Comment: Far better guide in duplicate link at top of the page

Comment: Thank you for re-directing me to another guide, but, unfortunately it still does not help/work with my current build/codes.

Answer (score 2):

For your example to work, you need to do the following, (when importing the name has to be the exact same as what you're exporting):

```
import {str} from './example1';
```

If you want to import str by default you need to to the following (when importing 
 you can name it whatever you wish it to be):

```
 //example1.js
 export default var str = 'hello world';

 //main.js
 import exampleStr from './example1';
```

If you're only exporting 1 object from your file, I recommend you use `default`, if you have multiple exports then use example 1.

Comment: Hey! Thank you for responding! I appreciate the help! 

Unfortunately, as I've tried exactly what you have typed, I still end up with an error:

**"Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token {"**

my main.js is completely blank for testing purposes and it only has what you have typed: import {str} from './example1';

along with the export:

export default var str = 'hello world';

Comment: @Zulu show me your webpack/babel config